# Validar multiple de archivos con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

¿Cómo están? Verán estoy haciendo una validación con [jquery](https://jquery.com/) de subida de archivos múltiples para lo cual tengo esto en el código html:

```
<input type="file" name="name_imagen[]" multiple="multiple" id="name_imagen">
```

y esto con jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type='submit']").prop("disabled",true);

    $("input[type='file']").bind('change',function(){
        var a = 0;
        var imageSize = $("#name_imagen").files.size;
        var ext = $('#name_imagen').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        for(var i = 0; i < imageSize; i ++){
            var imageSize1 = imageSize.files[i].size;
            if(imageSize1 > 1000000){
                alert("Mayor a lo permitido");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Al probarlo me sale este error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined

No se qué esté haciendo mal. A ésto mismo quiero agregarle la validación por extension de archivo.

Ayuda por favor. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es dentro del loop tienes :

```
var imageSize1 = imageSize.files[i].size;
```

debería ser :

```
var imageSize1 = imageSize.size;
```

Por otra parte te muestro otras formas de recorrer un [`Array-Like Object`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707568/javascript-difference-between-array-and-array-like-object), simplemente "descomenta" las lineas comentadas y mira el output :

```js
$("input[type='file']").bind('change',function(){
  // Esto es un Array-like Object
  //console.log(name_imagen.files);
   
  //var prueba = Array.from(filesObj);
  //console.log(prueba);
  
  var filesObj = name_imagen.files;

  var filesArray = Object.keys(filesObj).map(function(key){
    return filesObj[key];
  });
  
  filesArray.forEach(function(file){
    if (file.size > 1000000) 
      console.log(`El archivo ${file.name} tiene un tamaño (${file.size}) mayor del permitido`);
    else 
      console.log(`El archivo ${file.name} tiene un tamaño (${file.size}) CORRECTO!!!!!`)
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="name_imagen" multiple="multiple" id="name_imagen">
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta lo acabo de probar y funciona si ha eso quisiera agregarle una validación mas es decir que solo acepte ciertas extensiones de archivo lo hago dentro del foreach